# "RequestAnimationFrame()" FPS = Display refresh rate? is this affect the performance?

Tags: javascript

I tested the "RequestAnimationFrame()" method speed and I noticed that it fires exactly at the speed of my monitor refresh rate (60 / 100 / 144)

- I suppose the browser keeps track of the refresh rate of the display and applies it to the "RequestAnimationFrame" method
- I believe it does not affect the performance because it stacks multiple functions and executes them in the same frame.
- Am I right, can you please confirm These?

Comment: Well that is the whole point of the function..  What do you mean stacks?, it will only stack if you stack them.  Normally you don't call it again until the last callback has finished.  But if 2 parts of you code wanted to wait, then it would of course place them on a kind of stack to get rendered on the next frame.

Comment: I mean in 1 frame it stack multiple calls and executes them at the same time.

Comment: example: at 120 FPS display refresh rate the RequestAnimationFrame() still runs 60 FPS but if fires 2 per frame? (This is what I want to figure out)

Comment: I depends,  -> `The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation.`  IOW: it's down to the browser, they might even be settings inside the browser to allow / disallow faster frame rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, when you call `window.requestAnimationFrame`, what it does is keep in memory the function you provided as argument.

When the next DOM repaint happen (which happens the next time your monitor refreshes) it will empty the function stacks before it repaints the DOM.

This is particularly useful when you want to throttle for example a game loop or a scroll event listener (or any action that can be executed at a higher rate than your monitor refresh rate) allowing your program to compute to save performance